# ExpressJS res.send() not sending the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, supertest

I'm not sure why the `GET` request can't send me back the data
Basically, my `GET` request looks like:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
res.status(200).send(Buffer.from('<p>some html</p>'))
});
```

Then I use `supertest` to test this route.

```
  test('test', async () => {
    const res = await request(app)
      .get('/')

    expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
    expect(res.body.toString()).toBe("<p>some html</p>");
  });
```

Then I `console.log(res.body)`, it returns me the empty`{}`
I'm not sure why the route return give me the empty obj.

Comment: I dont think you need to send a buffer, express allows data as a plain string.

Answer (score 1):

The response data should be get from `res.text` not `res.body`.

`app.js`:

```js
const app = require('express')();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.status(200).send(Buffer.from('<p>some html</p>'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const app = require('./app');
const request = require('supertest');

describe('71328567', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const res = await request(app).get('/');
    expect(res.type).toBe('text/html');
    expect(res.text).toBe('<p>some html</p>');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71328567/app.test.js
  71328567
    ✓ should pass (26 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.657 s
```